# How do I fix the WHEREerror when I use LEFT JOIN and ON clauses

Tags: postgresql

I spent at least 4 hours trying to solve it, I tried a lot of solutions posted here, but I still didn't fix it.

That's my query:

```
SELECT * FROM l_article 
         INNER JOIN accounts_user 
         LEFT JOIN laws_marcacao ON (laws_marcacao.article_id = l_article.id 
                                AND laws_marcacao.user_id = accounts_user.id) 
         WHERE l_article.law_id = 1 and accounts_user.id = 1
```

Error is happening near `where`:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "where"
LINE 5:                        where l_article.law_id = 1 and accoun...
                               ^
```

Comment: NOTE:left JOINING your junction table will lead to a cathesian product. Is this your intention?

Comment: @wildplasser my intention is show all `l_article` tuples  with `laws_marcacao` and `accounts_user` associated to it. It was working good using sqlite, when I deployed it to a server that use postgres, I got this error.

Comment: @wildplasser you make me think about one point and I corrected it and it works. I did the change `LEFT JOIN accounts_user ON and accounts_user.id = 1`. Tku so much

Comment: Does it work when you leave out the complete `LEFT JOIN laws_marcacao ON (laws_marcacao.article_id = l_article.id                        AND laws_marcacao.user_id = accounts_user.id)` ? [currently it does nothing]

Comment: I just deleted this `and accounts_user.id = 1` and I changed the `inner join` to `left join` including `ON` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the inner join between l_article and accounts_user, it is missing a qualified join.

syntax:

```
T1 { [INNER] | { LEFT | RIGHT | FULL } [OUTER] } JOIN T2 ON boolean_expression
T1 { [INNER] | { LEFT | RIGHT | FULL } [OUTER] } JOIN T2 USING ( join column list )
T1 NATURAL { [INNER] | { LEFT | RIGHT | FULL } [OUTER] } JOIN T2
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/queries-table-expressions.html

So if you want to do a cartesian product then use CROSS JOIN instead of INNER JOIN. If you want to use INNER JOIN then you will need to have an join condition such as USING or ON clause.

Check out this [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/11666/10)

Comment: perfect. I was using the inner join without a ON clause. Tku

Answer (score 1):

A simple trick to keep the junction table out of the final result:

---

```
SELECT * 
FROM l_article a
JOIN accounts_user u ON EXISTS (
        SELECT * 
        FROM laws_marcacao xx
        WHERE xx.article_id = a.id                        
        AND xx.user_id = u.id
        )
WHERE a.law_id = 1 AND u.id = 1
  ;
```